# A module I uploaded block is displaying before the catalog category block. How do I change it?

Tags: xml, magento, magento-1.7

I downloaded a module to display pictures on my category page. All the category pages are displaying about the breadcrumbs, title, and static block within the referenced content under category default. I want to change the positioning so the images are displaying below everything within the content reference. How do I change the position and why is the module content being pulled first?

Answer (score 0):

The `before` and `after` attributes only work in one of two cases

When you insert into a `core/text_list` block

like your template block calls `getChildHtml` without any paramaters

For example

```
<reference name="root">
   <block type="core/template" name="example_block" after="content" template="page/html/example-block.phtml"/>
</reference>
```